# Ionic 2 - How to make a login post request?

Tags: angular, codeigniter, ionic-framework, ionic2

I need to implement login in my Ionic 2 app. For now I just need to be sure that the email and the password are properly received and get back a basic response.

I have successfully tested a GET request to the API and it is properly working, but I am not able to get the POST request working.

I have tried two approaches:

1. Using `subscribe`:

   **Login component:**

   ```
   submitLogin() 
   {
       var email = this.loginForm.value.email.trim();
       var password = this.loginForm.value.password.trim();

       this.userService.makeLogin(email, password);    
   }
   ```

   **Service:**

   ```
   makeLogin(email: string, password: string) 
   {
       var body = JSON.stringify({
           email: email,
           password: password
       });

       var headers = new Headers();
       headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');

       this.http
           .post(this.loginUrl, body, { headers: headers })
           .subscribe(data => {
                       console.log('login API success');
                       console.log(data);
                   }, error => {
                       console.log(JSON.stringify(error.json()));
           });
   }
   ```

   **The API** (codeIgniter): (code at minimum for testing purpose)

   ```
   public function testLoginIonic2()
   {
       header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
       header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

       $account_email  = $this->input->post('email');
       $account_password   = $this->input->post('password');

       echo json_encode($account_email);
   }
   ```

   **RESULT:**

   [image]

   The connection to the server seems okay - but no data is returned - the body of the response is empty
2. Using a `Promise`:

   **Login component:**

   ```
   submitLogin() 
   {
       var email = this.loginForm.value.email.trim();
       var password = this.loginForm.value.password.trim();

       this.userService.testLogin(email, password)
               .then(data => {
                   console.log('response data');
                   console.log(data);
               }); 
   }
   ```

   **Service:**

   ```
   testLogin(email: string, password: string): Promise<any> 
   {
       var body = JSON.stringify({
           email: email,
           password: password
       });

       var headers = new Headers();
       headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');

       return this.http
           .post(this.loginUrl, body, {headers: headers})
           .toPromise()
           .then(res => res.json().data);
   }
   ```

   **API:** Same as before

   **RESULT:**

   [image]

   I get this error message:  `Unexpected end of JSON input` (probably because the response is empty and thus not in JSON format).

*Why do I get an empty response?*

The form is properly working. The error is not there.

So there must be something wrong in the request, but what?

**EDIT:**

Testing with Postman it seems that the parameters are empty. Probably they are not properly sent.

Comment: because email is string type, I think it should be `echo json_encode({"email": $account_email});` because you expect the data is json format.  I don't know codeIgniter, so just a suggestion :-)

Comment: Use postman for example and try to call your backend. If it doesn't return what you're expecting, the pb is coming from your backend and has nothing to do with frontend or angular2.

Comment: very good suggestion! It really seems that in this way the parameters are not properly sent. That's why is empty the response.. In Postman it happens the same if the parameters are setup as raw data. If instead i enter them as x-www-form-urlencoded or form-data then i properly get back the email as a response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the replies.

The answer from @hgoebl is properly working.

I found a solution that is a bit more simple using `URLSearchParams`:

**Component**:

```
submitLogin() 
{
    var email = this.loginForm.value.email.trim();
    var password = this.loginForm.value.password.trim();

    this.userService.makeLogin(email, password)
        .subscribe((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

**Service**:

```
makeLogin(email: string, password: string) 
{       
    let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    urlSearchParams.append('email', email);
    urlSearchParams.append('password', password);
    let body = urlSearchParams.toString()

    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');

    return this.http
        .post(this.loginUrl, body, { headers: headers })
        .map(response => response.json())
}
```

Keep in mind that `URLSearchParams` has to be imported in the service:

```
import { Http, Headers, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
```

**EDIT**:

I moved the subscribe inside the component to be able to handle the response data inside the component.

Answer (score 2):

For me it looks like if the problem starts by sending in the wrong format.
You're telling the server it's content is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but you're sending JSON.

You might try this:

```
testLogin(email: string, password: string): Promise<any> 
{
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type',
        'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');

    let params = {email, password};
    let body = this.toFormUrlEncoded(params);

    //... your post request
}

private toFormUrlEncoded(object: Object): string {
    return Object.keys(object)
        .map(key => {
            return encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + 
                   encodeURIComponent(object[key]);
        })
    .join('&');
}
```

As an alternative you could also change your content-type to JSON and change your server to decode JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you do `map` after `http.post`?

```
this.http
    .post(this.loginUrl, body, { headers: headers })
    .map(response => response.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
        console.log('login API success');
        console.log(data);
    }, e => {
         console.log(e);
    });
```

Your response from the observables looks ok, but not parsed.

Comment: You are absolutely right! It was missing! In this way change the way I get the response. Not a string but as a clean json. Thanks!