# How to implement Forgot password using POST REST API in Ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, auth-guard, ionic-auth-service

Ionic 4: How to implement Forgot password functionality using the POST method: REST API?

I've already checked the user with REST API and it's validated but I'm not sure how to send the validated user's email and new the password with 2 fields like new password & update password.

**NOTE:** If my question isn't clear kindly suggest me forgot password API

**This is the API to update the password:**
Method:
POST

URL:
https://www.abcd.com/updatePassword

Request:

```
{"email": "test@test.com", "userId":"1234567890", "password":"test", "confirmPassword":"test" }
```

Failure:

```
{"code":"401","data":{}}

{"code":"401","data":{},"message":"Password and Confirm Password Not Matching"}
```

Success:

```
{"code":"200","data":{"status":"success"},"message":"Updated Successfully!"}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ionic 2 - How to make a login post request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40723010/ionic-2-how-to-make-a-login-post-request)

Comment: nope. Anyway thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

if user will forget password then user only know it's mail id so then you can send reset password link or old password via e-mail.